# SDDM starts with wrong screen size on LG 27UD68-W 4K Monitor

Tags: opensuse, resolution, sddm

SDDM starts with wrong screen size: according to startup the screen size is set to 3840x2160 which is supported by the monitor but not supported by the graphic card (**starting X server with a higher DPI give even worse images**)

```
[    26.011] (II) RADEON(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    26.011] (II) RADEON(0): Output DVI-1 using initial mode 3840x2160 +0+0
[    26.011] (II) RADEON(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    26.011] (II) RADEON(0): mem size init: gart size :1fdff000 vram size: s:20000000 visible:df9c000
[    26.011] (II) RADEON(0): EXA: Driver will allow EXA pixmaps in VRAM
[    26.011] (==) RADEON(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
```

Log file: https://pastebin.com/6bw67EQV
Monitor data: https://pastebin.com/b9U51WET

How can I configure SDDM to start in 1920x1080? I tried to set GRUB_GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub with no result and now I need some help in changing /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-monitor.conf which contain the #Section "Monitor" of X11 configuration.

Someone can sande me a working example of X11 configuration with more than 1 mode listed? The example found so far contains only one resolution.

Thanks in advance